# How can I remove unnecessary toolbar accidentally installed on my browser?

Tags: browser, toolbar

I got irritated by unwanted toolbar on my browser, it makes my system slow.
i tried to uninstall this, but I didn't find anything from where i can uninstall this.
i tried control panel too, this is not there.

[image]

I marked the toolbar in red rectangle.
if anyone have idea how can i uninstall this, please share with me. it very irritating.

Comment: You should probably ask this at superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool bar probably would be installed as an add-on. Which can be removed from Tools -> Add-Ons.